# Keep adding items in a list after clicking a button

Tags: c#, list

I have a simple mobile app in xamarin.forms. I have a button that when clicked triggers a method which scans a code via the camera. Once scanned, it gets the number. However, I want to scan several codes and stores the corresponding number. Hence, after each scans, I will click the button again to scan.

My code in C# is as follows:

```
public async void StoreNum()
{   
    ListNumbers = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    var num = await ScanCodeVM.CodePage(); // returns a string

    if (num != null)
    {
        ListNumbers.Add(num);     
    }
}
```

> The issue is that the list is holding one number. After another scan,
>   it deletes the previous number and stores the new number.

My question is how can I make it stores previous numbers as well ?

Comment: Do not create new instance of `ListNumbers` on every click. Instantiate list when application start for example.

Comment: Oh. Is that the culprit ? or should I declare `var num` as an array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me, you need to create your list outside of this function and add/ remove form that in another function.

```
  ListNumbers = new ObservableCollection<string>();
 public async void StoreNum()
{   

var num = await ScanCodeVM.CodePage(); // returns a string

if (num != null)
{
    ListNumbers.Add(num);     
}
}

 // do something with that list.
```

Comment: How can I check if the list already contains a number that has already been added ? if so, then it will not add it.

Comment: Call the ListNumbers.Contains("value") method to check first before adding it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instantiate collection of numbers outside of the click method
2. For having only unique numbers in the collection use
   `HashSet<string>`

```cs
public class NumberReader
{
    public HashSet<string> Numbers { get; set; }

    // Numbers instantiated in constructor
    public NumberReader()
    {
        Numbers = new HashSet<string>();
    }

    // Executed when user click a button
    public async Task Read()
    {
        var number = await ScanCodeVm.CodePage();
        if (number != null)
        {
            Numbers.Add(number);
        }
    }
}
```

`HashSet<T>.Add` method will add only unique values. It returns `true` when given value was added successfully and `false` when given value already exist in the set.

Do not use `async void` for functions - because all possible exceptions will be "swallowed". But it is ok to use `async void` for event handlers.

Comment: Thank you for your help also :) 

`Do not use async void for functions - because all possible exceptions will be "swallowed". But it is ok to use async void for event handlers.`

Can you explain further ?

Comment: From there: [https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), check paragraph about "Return types"